# What can I do when seeing an obviously wrong answer, but can't comment or flag?

Tags: discussion, new-users, wrong-answers

I spend some time on Stack Exchange communities, and have been a user for 5 months. I've joined a new subcommunity, so my reputation is low (actually it's just 1) and read some question and answers.

One of them contains, to be nice, untruth. **What can a newbie do with that?**

I can't flag it, I can't comment it, I can't downvote it. One thing, which I did, is that I can edit this post (and in the edit summary, write what and why is false), but an OP has to apply my changes to be public. So if he/she doesn't agree with me, it is senseless.

**Did I miss something?** I understand Stack's communities are places, where many people meet each other, so **there must be restrictions; but aren't they too severe?**

Comment: *I can't flag it, I can't comment it, I can't downvote it.* Make some good edits to get you to [15 rep to unlock the privilege: flag posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?

Comment: @rene - yea, you are right, I corrected my post. That's why I'm asking about new users. Isn't it weird I need 15 reps to say public 'hey dude, water isn't boilling in 50 Celsius, it's false'.

Comment: @Szkaplerny Less weird than if you were able to say "cheap viagra to keep you going all night loooooong, click here ---> " at 1 rep.

Comment: *Untruth on the internet???*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try any combination of:

- You could write your own answer which directly contradicts the other, with a good explanation that will show why the other answer is wrong. No need to call out the author of the other answer, or even address it directly, but if the community sees two contradictory answers, I expect they'll vote up the answer that's provably true.
- You could mark the question/answer (Favorite, browser bookmark, etc.) and come back to it later when you've managed to garner enough reputation to be able to flag/comment/etc.
- You could bring it up on the site's Meta (assuming you've got the 5 reputation points you need), but I'd only do that if it's something egregious.

Or you could simply forget about it and move on with your life.

Comment: Last idea is often the correct one which people should choose on Internet ;)
I guess I'm not very first with these questions, so probably there is nothing to change in this case (and this is why I wrote this post).
Anyway your answer is good enough to just accept it, keep in mind and move on.

Comment: Your first point deserves more emphasis and explanation; it's difficult at times, but rewarding.

Comment: I would move on, or when you can flag, ***Flag and move on.*** (if a flag is truly needed)

Answer (score 10):

Al's answer about what you can do is correct, but I want to address two bad premises in your question.

First, **never edit for factual incorrectness.** Not a suggested edit, and not a regular edit either. If the answer says "There are 7" when in fact there are 8, or 193, or 0, an edit is **never** the way to fix it. Edits are for spelling, grammar, formatting, bringing in information that was added in comments, bringing in links or images (that you have checked) the original poster wasn't allowed to add, and so on. Never changing meaning.

Second, **never flag for factual incorrectness.** Unless the incorrectness is more like irrelevance (someone asks how long to roast a chicken for and the answer is about good uses for leftover roast chicken) in which case flagging as not an answer may be good, but only if you can comment to explain why it's not an answer to the asked question. But just "This answer contains technical inaccuracies" is not a flagging reason or a ruling moderators will ever make.

So your inability to edit or flag are not relevant to your "someone is wrong on the internet" problem. The absolutely best solution, and one available to all users, is to add a correct answer and let the voters figure it out. The other answerer may edit or delete their answer, or not, but you have put the correct answer out there and that has value.